# SBT Deependency Issues

Tags: scala, hadoop, sbt

**Hey Guys, I am trying to create a jar file(Complie) using SBT. My dependency file is below :**

```
    name := "MyFirstSparkProject"
    version := "1.0"
    scalaVersion := "2.10.4"
  libraryDependencies ++= Seq("org.apache.spark" % "spark-core_2.11" % "2.0.0" exclude ("org.apache.hadoop","hadoop-yarn-server-web-proxy"),
   "org.apache.spark" % "spark-sql_2.10" % "1.6.0" exclude      ("org.apache.hadoop","hadoop-yarn-server-web-proxy"),
  "org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-common" % "2.7.0" exclude ("org.apache.hadoop","hadoop-yarn-server-web-proxy"),
  "org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-common" % "2.7.0" exclude ("javax.servlet", "servlet-api"),
  "org.apache.spark" % "spark-hive_2.10" % "1.6.0" exclude ("org.apache.hadoop","hadoop-yarn-server-web-proxy"),
  "org.apache.spark" % "spark-yarn_2.10" % "1.6.0" exclude ("org.apache.hadoop","hadoop-yarn-server-web-proxy")
)
```

**I am getting an error saying :**

```
[error] Modules were resolved with conflicting cross-version suffixes in {file:/C:/MySbt/}mysbt:
[error]    org.apache.spark:spark-launcher _2.11, _2.10
[error]    org.json4s:json4s-ast _2.11, _2.10
[error]    org.apache.spark:spark-network-shuffle _2.11, _2.10
[error]    com.twitter:chill _2.11, _2.10
[error]    org.json4s:json4s-jackson _2.11, _2.10
[error]    com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-scala _2.11, _2.10
[error]    org.json4s:json4s-core _2.11, _2.10
[error]    org.apache.spark:spark-unsafe _2.11, _2.10
[error]    org.apache.spark:spark-core _2.11, _2.10
[error]    org.apache.spark:spark-network-common _2.11, _2.10
java.lang.RuntimeException: Conflicting cross-version suffixes in: org.apache.spark:spark-launcher, org.json4s:json4s-ast, org.apache.spark:spark-network-shuffle, com.twitter:chill, org.json4s:json4s-jackson, com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-scala, org.json4s:json4s-core, org.apache.spark:spark-unsafe, org.apache.spark:spark-core, org.apache.spark:spark-network-common
        at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:27)
        at sbt.ConflictWarning$.processCrossVersioned(ConflictWarning.scala:46)
        at sbt.ConflictWarning$.apply(ConflictWarning.scala:32)
        at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$100.apply(Defaults.scala:1253)
        at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$100.apply(Defaults.scala:1250)
        at scala.Function1$$anonfun$compose$1.apply(Function1.scala:47)
        at sbt.$tilde$greater$$anonfun$$u2219$1.apply(TypeFunctions.scala:40)
        at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$4.work(System.scala:63)
        at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:228)
        at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:228)
        at sbt.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:17)
```

Can someone help me resove this dependency? i know that this is being caused by conflicting libraries

Comment: Read http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Cross-Build.html.

Comment: Your "spark-core_2.11" is for Scala 2.11 an your project's Scala version is "2.10"? Maybe use "%%" without "_2.whatever".